# insert PNG images in PDF using FlateDecode

Tags: android, pdf, png

I can insert JPEG images into PDF using DCTDecode Successfully but while inserting PNG's using FlateDecode facing problem such as images are not shown in PDF. I read All byte data from PNG image and written to PDF file as same ,as done with JPEG Images. But all the PDF Pages are blank.

Is there any procedure to encode PNG byte Data before embedding into pdf while using FlateDecode?

Is there any other Procedure to embed PNG images to PDF without using FlateDecode ?
please suggest...

Comment: PDF does not know png directly, you have to transform the image format, cf. The PDF specification.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,My main intention is decrease pdf size, if i use PNG's PDF size is almost 10 times less compare to PDF with JPEG images.Without variation in size and clarity is there any way to transform image format.

Comment: How do you process PDF files? Do you use some known PDF library (e.g. IText) or have you coded the methods yourself? In the former case the library contain the code for correct bitmap image insertion. In the latter you had better study the spec.

Comment: I coded my self for PDF files, I referred PDF SPEC but could n't found  relevent example or complete information for inserting PNG images..

Comment: Section 8.9.5 explains how bitmap images are embedded. Pngs are not embedded as is, though, but are transformed. You might want to look at open source PDF libraries for inspiration, e.g. iText or pdfbox.